# External ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity login throws System.ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

I use external authentication in my ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity web application. The authentication is implemented using Google account. The registration process goes just fine using Google account, but when I try to log-in (already been registered previously) an exception occurs in this part of code: `var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);`
The whole code snippet goes just like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
    var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    if (loginInfo == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }

    try//just to catch an exception in the next line
    {
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The exception is this:

> Message: The value can not be undefined!
>
> ParamName: "value"
>
> Source: mscorlib

..though I don't have any "value" properties in 'loginInfo' variable to be undefined!

Comment: Generally speaking Stack Overflow is handled in English.  The exception in your pic is in a Cyrillic language.  Translate it first and ask for help with that message.  

Additionally, you can directly insert a picture into a Stack Overflow post instead of linking out to a picture.  This way, if the picture eventually goes away, then the post doesn't get a broken link.

Comment: I translated the exception message info...concerning the picture, I couldn't insert it directly because of rep or whatever there is

Answer (score 0):

I found a misktake. The thing was that when you register using third-party services(as in my case Google), you have to make sure that all the fields that marked as [Required] has to be filled directly in the method!

Just like this:

```
var name = info.ExternalIdentity.Name.Split(' ');
user.LastName = name[1];
user.FirstName = name[0];
```

In such a method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginConfirmation(ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel model, string returnUrl, bool registerAsDoctor)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Home");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var info = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (info == null)
            {
                return View("ExternalLoginFailure");
            }

            var user = (registerAsDoctor) ? (ApplicationUser)
                          new Doctor(model.Email) : new Patient(model.Email);

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var name = info.ExternalIdentity.Name.Split(' ');
                user.LastName = name[1];
                user.FirstName = name[0];

                result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, info.Login);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, (registerAsDoctor) ? "Doctor" : "Patient");
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    RedirectToAction("MyProfile", "Home");
                }
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Because if one misses it, the registration will pass just fine, but on the next log-in, it will throw an exception, that some "value" can not be null!